# convert json to datatable vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wcf

```
Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
Dim dataStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
```

Using this code getting response from responseFromServer is like this

> "{ "RefNumber":"11b1b72d-84a2-4d97-9f3c-67fb6dc57210","Status":"S"}"

I need to convert this json string  into data table .

Comment: `dim myTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataTable)($"[{responseFromServer}]")`. Assuming that's all the JSON response. Is it?

Comment: `Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()`    , the output from responsefromserver is "{ "RefNumber":"11b1b72d-84a2-4d97-9f3c-67fb6dc57210","Status":"S"}"   is that string form or json format.  if it is  string how to convert string to json after that need convert json to datatable . please help me i'm bit confused.

Comment: A JSON is a string, you don't *convert string to json*, you *convert* (Deserialize) a JSON string to a Type. In this case, you're asking how to deserialize your JSON response to a DataTable Type. Do you have `Json.Net` or `System.Text.Json` available in your Project? -- Note that your JSON represents a single object, so it's not directly convertibe to a DataTable, which assumes an array of objects. That's why I've enclosed your JSON in square brackets: `$"[{responseFromServer}]"`.

Answer (score 0):

[**With Newtonsoft library "Json.NET"**](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

You need to edit your JSON string and then you can deserialize your JSON into a dataset.

[Here a working example on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lYZYIf)

```
    Dim jsonString As String = "{""RefNumber"":""11b1b72d-84a2-4d97-9f3c-67fb6dc57210"",""Status"":""S""}"
    
    jsonString = "{""YourTableName"": [" + jsonString + "] }"

    Console.WriteLine(jsonString)

    Dim ds As DataSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(of DataSet)(jsonString)
    
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Console.WriteLine("## " + ds.Tables("YourTableName").TableName + " ##")
    Console.WriteLine("-------------------")
    Console.WriteLine("")

    For Each r as DataRow in ds.Tables("YourTableName").Rows
        Console.WriteLine(r("RefNumber").ToString() + " - " + r("Status").ToString())
    next
```